# Por que keybd_event não funciona em alguns contextos?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Quero entender porque o keybd_event não funciona em alguns contextos. Por exemplo, ele não funciona em jogos com League of Legends ou jogos emulados no ePSXe.

O seguinte código:

```
Keys key = Keys.Q;

keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, 0x0001 | 0, 0);
keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, 0x0001 | 0x0002, 0);
```

Funciona em jogos como Terraria, mas não funciona nos jogos que mencionei anteriormente.

Entretanto, eu notei que se eu tentar apertar <kbd>Esc</kbd> no ePSXe, funciona e sou levado para tela principal. O comando ativou uma ação do emulador, mas não ativa ações do jogo. Acredito que o mesmo aconteça em League of Legends.

Por que não funciona exatamente? Existe talvez uma maneira de fazer isto funcionar?

Comment: Vale lembrar que esta função é nativa e não do .Net. Segundo o MSDN ela também foi ultrapassada por `SendInput`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Isso provavelmente não resolverá o seu "problema", já que possivelmente esta relacionado a maneira como o aplicativo obtenha a entrada de dados do usuário.

Comment: Provavelmente é porque as aplicações (jogos) em questão devem estar fazendo leitura do teclado diretamente no dispositivo e não usando a API do Windows. Caso eles estejam usando o DirectX para leitura do teclado, pode ser que o DirectX faça a leitura direta do dispositivo. Vale testar um exemplo simples de leitura de teclado em DirectX e testar seu programa.

Comment: @BrunoLM você pode esclarescer mais o contexto? Você está sob o DirectX? Usa o XNA? Já verificou os eventos de teclado Win32?

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você só deve usar o flag 0x0001 (KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY) quando você quiser especificar que a tecla apertada foi a do teclado numérico.

Segundo existe dois modos de uma aplicação receber entrada do teclado:

- Processando as mensagens WM_KEYUP e WM_KEYDOWN da sua pilha de mensagens
- Verificando o estado das teclas em tempo real

Aplicações comuns do Windows geralmente usam a primeira opção, já jogos geralmente usam a segunda pois a eles só interessa as teclas que estão pressionadas naquele momento e não o que foi pressionado 100 milissegundos atrás.

O que a função keybd_event faz é criar uma mensagem WM_KEYUP ou WM_KEYDOWN com a tecla que você apertou e jogar na pilha de mensagens da janela que está com foco no momento, se a aplicação em questão não recebe suas entradas através de mensagens o keybd_event não vai funcionar.